# How can we run a custom command in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, command

I want to run a custom command say "`run mspaint.exe`" from eclipse..How can i do that? I want to run more complex commands written by me but i want to run from eclipse because the resources are in my workspace generated on some program compilation..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
run > external tool > external tool configurations...
```

for paint say,

```
Name: run paint
Location: C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe
```

done. you can see this menu. and execute.

Well, since paint just opened, lets get a screenshot for you :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can use internal DSL when defining an external tool. Instead of `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe` one writes `${system_path:calc}`.

Full list of supported functions:

https://help.eclipse.org/2022-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm